# Implementing SVM for multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, svm

I want to know if it is possible to have multiple CSV files for the training and one file for testing.

For example I got four CSV files that contain 8 columns of data and one for the label which is different from all my 4 CSV training files.

With all this data, I want to test on a test.scv file which contains only 8 columns of data and adds the predicted label in the same file. ( not sure how)

I managed to do it for only one CSV file for testing and training
Here is the code below:

```
svm_data = pd.read_csv('excel1.csv')


classifcator=svm_data[['alpha','beta','gama','teta','low_alpha','high_alpha','low_beta','high_beta']]

X=np.asarray(classifcator)

y=svm_data['label']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# here not sure how to train_test_split with multiple csv files and one for training
X_train, X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2) 

from sklearn import preprocessing

X_train = preprocessing.scale(X_train)
X_test = preprocessing.scale(X_test)

classifier=SVC(kernel='linear')   

classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)


Y_predict = classifier.predict(X_test)


print(classification_report(y_test,Y_predict))
```

All I need is an example of multiple csv files for training if it is possible. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`train_test_split` is for splitting one set of data into train/test data - if you already have it separated by file then just read each file separately to create your train/test datasets and don't use that function.